# numpy array to GTiff using rasterio without source raster

Tags: python, raster, lidar, numpy, rasterio

I have a numpy array that represents rasterized data from a LiDAR point cloud. For example:

```
import numpy as np
import rasterio

arr = np.random.randint(5, size = (100, 100))
```

I know information about this rasterized data already, such as the pixel size, the top left coordinate, and the coordinate reference system (as a wkt string, but I can change this if needed):

```
min_x = 472137
max_y = 5015782
pixel_size = 0.5
wkt = 'PROJCS["NAD83(CSRS) / UTM zone 10N",GEOGCS["NAD83(CSRS)",DATUM["NAD83_Canadian_Spatial_Reference_System",SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6140"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4617"]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",-123],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH],AUTHORITY["EPSG","3157"]]PROJCS["NAD83(NSRS2007) / UTM zone 10N",GEOGCS["NAD83(NSRS2007)",DATUM["NAD83_National_Spatial_Reference_System_2007",SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6759"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4759"]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",-123],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH],AUTHORITY["EPSG","3717"]]PROJCS["NAD83(HARN) / UTM zone 10N",GEOGCS["NAD83(HARN)",DATUM["NAD83_High_Accuracy_Reference_Network",SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6152"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4152"]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",-123],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH],AUTHORITY["EPSG","3740"]]PROJCS["NAD83(2011) / UTM zone 10N",GEOGCS["NAD83(2011)",DATUM["NAD83_National_Spatial_Reference_System_2011",SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","1116"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6318"]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",-123],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6339"]]PROJCS["NAD27 / UTM zone 10N",GEOGCS["NAD27",DATUM["North_American_Datum_1927",SPHEROID["Clarke 1866",6378206.4,294.9786982138982,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7008"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6267"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4267"]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",-123],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH],AUTHORITY["EPSG","26710"]]PROJCS["NAD83 / UTM zone 10N",GEOGCS["NAD83",DATUM["North_American_Datum_1983",SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6269"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4269"]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",-123],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH],AUTHORITY["EPSG","26910"]]PROJCS["WGS 72 / UTM zone 10N",GEOGCS["WGS 72",DATUM["WGS_1972",SPHEROID["WGS 72",6378135,298.26,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7043"]],TOWGS84[0,0,4.5,0,0,0.554,0.2263],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6322"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4322"]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",-123],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH],AUTHORITY["EPSG","32210"]]PROJCS["WGS 72BE / UTM zone 10N",GEOGCS["WGS 72BE",DATUM["WGS_1972_Transit_Broadcast_Ephemeris",SPHEROID["WGS 72",6378135,298.26,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7043"]],TOWGS84[0,0,1.9,0,0,0.814,-0.38],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6324"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4324"]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",-123],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH],AUTHORITY["EPSG","32410"]]PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 10N",GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",-123],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH],AUTHORITY["EPSG","32610"]]'
```

Looking at the cookbooks for rasterio, only examples of writing rasters after the metadata from some source raster is included. In fact, this specific question is missing from [their cookbook](https://mapbox.s3.amazonaws.com/playground/perrygeo/rasterio-docs/cookbook.html#creating-raster-from-numpy-array).

How can I construct the metadata (or `profile` I think rasterio calls it) to prepare the numpy array for writing to file?

Comment: Are you insistent upon using rasterio? I have some script that uses gdal/osr to get the job done.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This ended up being more straightforward than I thought, with all of the capabilities lying in the `rasterio.open` function.

Here is an example using a proj4 string instead of `wkt`.

```
import rasterio
from rasterio.transform import from_origin

arr = np.random.randint(5, size=(100,100)).astype(np.float)

transform = from_origin(472137, 5015782, 0.5, 0.5)

new_dataset = rasterio.open('test1.tif', 'w', driver='GTiff',
                            height = arr.shape[0], width = arr.shape[1],
                            count=1, dtype=str(arr.dtype),
                            crs='+proj=utm +zone=10 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs',
                            transform=transform)

new_dataset.write(arr, 1)
new_dataset.close()
```