# Weird coordinates after converting numpy array to raster

Tags: python, coordinate-system, rasterio, numpy

I have the NumPy array and its bounding box coordinates. I have tried to convert it into raster using rasterio, based on [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/279953/numpy-array-to-gtiff-using-rasterio-without-source-raster), and it did save it as raster, but when I use rasterio.show the coordinates are very wrong.

This is the script I have used:

```
bbox_coords_wgs84=[-101.7359960059834, 20.21904081937658, -100.5717967351885, 20.8312118894487]

#variables for the projection:
minx=bbox_coords_wgs84[0]
maxy=bbox_coords_wgs84[3]
pixel_size= 10

#according to the post on GIS SO:

import rasterio
from rasterio.transform import from_origin

transform=from_origin(minx,maxy,pixel_size,pixel_size)
crs_img='EPSG:4326'


with rasterio.open('test1.tif', 
                    'w',
                    driver='GTiff',
                    height=ndvi.shape[0],
                    width=ndvi.shape[1],
                    count=1,
                    dtype=ndvi.dtype,
                    crs=crs_img,
                    nodata=None, # change if data has nodata value
                    transform=transform) as dst:
        dst.write(ndvi, 1)
 
#display the results:

from matplotlib import pyplot
from rasterio.plot import show

src = rasterio.open('test1.tif')
show(src)
```

[image]

As you can see, the numbers are absolutely not the correct coordinates.

My end goal: to be able to reproject the NumPy array into WGS84 correctly.

*This post relates also to [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/383332/reproject-a-numpy-array-with-affine-transform)

Comment: You could use gdal translate if you want to transform the raster image or pyproj to transform the coordinates in the numpy array

Comment: You do not report that this is a suite of [Reproject a NumPy array with affine transform](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/383332/reproject-a-numpy-array-with-affine-transform) where you use `rasterio.transform.from_bounds` and not  `rasterio.transform.from_origin`

Comment: @gene I have edited now with reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not report that this is a suite of [Reproject a NumPy array with affine transform](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/383332/reproject-a-numpy-array-with-affine-transform) where you use `rasterio.transform.from_bounds`

From [rasterio.transform module](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.transform.html)

> **rasterio.transform.from_bounds(west, south, east, north, width, height)**
> Return an Affine transformation given bounds, width and height.
> Return an Affine transformation for a georeferenced raster given its bounds west, south, east, north and its width and height in number of pixels.

And

> **rasterio.transform.from_origin(west, north, xsize, ysize)**
> Return an Affine transformation given upper left and pixel sizes.
> Return an Affine transformation for a georeferenced raster given the coordinates of its upper left corner west, north and pixel sizes xsize, ysize.

It is not the same thing and the results are different

```
rasterio.transform.from_bounds( -101.7359960059834,20.21904081937658,-100.5717967351885,20.8312118894487,1103,2039)
Affine(0.0010554843796871222, 0.0, -101.7359960059834,
   0.0, -0.0003002310299519955, 20.8312118894487)

rasterio.transform.from_origin(-101.7359960059834,20.8312118894487,10,10)
Affine(10.0, 0.0, -101.7359960059834,
   0.0, -10.0, 20.8312118894487)
```

## New

The four corners of the raster from the bound (width = 1103, height= 2039)

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(0,0,'ro')
ax.plot(1103,0,'bo')
ax.plot(0,2039,'go')
ax.plot(1103,2039,'co')
plt.show()
```

[image]

The transformation

```
 trans = rasterio.transform.from_bounds(-101.7359960059834,20.21904081937658-100.5717967351885,20.8312118894487,1103,2039)

 
trans*(0,0)
(-101.7359960059834, 20.8312118894487)
trans*(1103,0) 
(-100.5717967351885, 20.8312118894487)
trans*(0,2039) 
(-101.7359960059834, 20.21904081937658)
trans*(1103,2039)
(-100.5717967351885, 20.21904081937658)

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(*(trans*(0,0)),'ro')
ax.plot(*(trans*(1103,0)),'bo')
ax.plot(*(trans*(0,2039)),'go')
ax.plot(*(trans*(1103,2039)),'co')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: sorry , I feel now more confused. How can I georeference my numpy array correctly? which one should I use?

Comment: `rasterio.transform.from_bounds` if you use bounds

Comment: look above in New